# CreateObject equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, vb.net, com, createobject

I have read a lot of similar topics in this forum and in the internet, but I didn't find the solution for my problem.

I'm just trying to convert this VB lines in C++:

```
Dim OR As Object
Dim info as String
OR = CreateObject("ORIG.API")
info = OR.info()
```

Could you please tell me the translation in C++ ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: Thank you, I get the point :) I'm sorry about it!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [CoCreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Do not forget to call CLSIDFromProgID and CoInitialize before calling CoCreateInstance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add the required headers. Please notice that the `atlmfc` library need to be installed from Visual Studio Installer:

```cpp
// cl /Zi /Od /DEBUG:FULL -IE:\VisualStudio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\lib\x86 -IE:\VisualStudio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\atlmfc\include /EHsc .\test.cpp /link /libpath:"E:\VisualStudio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\lib\x86" atls.lib /DEBUG:FULL ; .\test.exe
#pragma comment(lib, "Ole32.lib")
#include <Windows.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#include <combaseapi.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
```

Then, use [CoInitialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objbase/nf-objbase-coinitialize) and [CoUninitialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-couninitialize) before and after your call:

```cpp
int main() {
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    
    // Your code here    

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Then, fetch the object using [CLSIDFromProgID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-clsidfromprogid), and store it in `clsid`:

```cpp
HRESULT hr;
CLSID clsid;
hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"ORIG.API", &clsid);
```

Then, create a Dispatcher using [CoCreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance):

```cpp
IDispatch *pOR;
hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IDispatch, (void **)&pOR);
```

Then, get the method you need using [IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nf-oaidl-idispatch-getidsofnames):

```cpp
DISPID PropertyID[1] = {0};
BSTR PropName[1];
PropName[0] = SysAllocString(L"info");
hr = pOR->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, PropName, 1, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, PropertyID);
```

Finally, Invoke it using [IDispatch::Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nf-oaidl-idispatch-invoke). Here I showed how to pass 2 string arguments, and you might modify them according to your need:

```cpp
DISPPARAMS dp = {NULL, NULL, 0, 0};
VARIANT vResult;
EXCEPINFO ei;
UINT uArgErr;

// Allocate memory for the arguments array
dp.rgvarg = new VARIANT[2];
if (dp.rgvarg == NULL)
    return E_OUTOFMEMORY;

// Set the number of arguments
dp.cArgs = 2;

// Initialize the arguments as empty variants
VariantInit(&dp.rgvarg[0]);
VariantInit(&dp.rgvarg[1]);

// Set the arguments as BSTRs
BSTR account = SysAllocString(L"1234567");
BSTR pwd = SysAllocString(L"123456");
dp.rgvarg[0].vt = VT_BSTR;
dp.rgvarg[0].bstrVal = pwd;
dp.rgvarg[1].vt = VT_BSTR;
dp.rgvarg[1].bstrVal = account;

VariantInit(&vResult);

// Call the function using Invoke
hr = pOR->Invoke(PropertyID[0], IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &dp, &vResult, &ei, &uArgErr);

// Free the memory for the arguments array
delete[] dp.rgvarg;

// Convert the BSTR to a char*
char *strResult;

strResult = _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(vResult.bstrVal);

// Use the char* result
cout << "result: " << strResult << endl;

// Free the memory for the BSTR and the char*
delete[] strResult;
VariantClear(&vResult);
```